# Calling 2 views from a single view depending upon which segment is chosen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

A bit of a confusion for me but I'm sure I'm making a very small mistake. Please guide me in the right direction. 
Here is what the situation is.

I have a OneViewController which has 2 segments. The code for segment1 is already working as it is written in OneViewController(not a tableviewController but I want to display a tableView so manually written the code for it) because Segment1 is by default selected. And when I click on segment 2, I have to display another tableViewController(for which I have created a class called TwoTableViewController). And I want that both tableViews should appear in the same view (no pushing of new views). **The most important thing is that the segmented control should never disappear.**

I have also attached the relevant part of the code. I know I have asked a similar question before, but it was really confusion so I thought to start afresh. Hope I'm forgiven! :)

Here's the code:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
  //has the elements I want to display when I click on segment 1. since it is already selected , I have written it here
}
    -(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged
    {
         switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmnentIndex)
         {
            case 0:
             //default first index selected. 
             [tableView setHidden:NO];
             if(self.view viewWithTag==9999]{
              [[self.view viewWithTag:9999]removeFromSuperView]; 
                  }
              break;

             case 1:
             NewTableViewController *controller=[[NewTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewTableViewController" bundle:nil];
             [controller.view setTag:9999];         
             break;
             default:
             break;
         }
    }
```

NewTableViewController has separate methods and the datasource and delegate are set to TableView in the IB. All I want to do is call this NewTableViewController when I click on Segment2.

Answer (score 0):

Better to populate and write the codes for  UITableViews in same class (in **OneViewController**)

You can identify the curresponding tableView through the below way

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

     int numberOfSections = 0;

     if(tableView == yourTableViewOne){

           numberOfSections =  5;
       }

     else if (tableView == yourTableViewTwo){

          numberOfSections = return 3;
     }

  return numberOfSections;
}
```

Use the same check in all other UITableView delegates.

Comment: And I dont want the segmented control to disappear once I click on Segment 2.

Comment: so write the conditions and codes for it.. i didn't get your comment exactly.. please elaborate..

Comment: Ok..here's the thing. where should I write the viewDidLoad of the NewTableViewController?

Comment: you can download sample app zip from here https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/downloads  see the app TwoTableViews .. it will give you the clear picture

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in `Case 1:` of your `-(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged`

```
[self.view addSubview:self.YourTableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//view1,view2 are uiviews not a view controllers-(IBAction) segmentedControlChanged

-(void)segcontrol
{
    if(segments.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
      self.view=view1;

    }
    else 
    {
        self.view=view2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show second view controller either by pushing it on a navigation controller OR by presenting modally OR use a tabbar controller instead of segmentedcontrol.

My piece of suggestion is

Declare a class which subclasses UIViewController. Add a segmentedControl at the bottom and a uitableview above it.

Whenever user clicks a segment, reload tableview with corresponding data. This way you can save memory. And you need not take the pain of removing/adding/hiding views ..